# Selection function comments while expanding in Lisp modes

Tags: function, emacs, comments, selection

I'm using a keyboard shortcut bound to:

```
er/expand-region, which is an interactive Lisp function in `expand-region-core.el'.
```

to expand the region.

For example when I want to select a function and move it around.

My problem is that if I want to select any function like, say:

```
;; some comment related to the function
(defn foo [x]
  ...)
```

I cannot "expand" to include ";; some comment".  As soon as I expand more than the function (without the comment) it expends the full buffer.

While I'd like it to first expand to include the function and the comment and then the full buffer.

It's bothering me so much that I'm temporarily doing this as a workaround:

```
(defn foo [x]
  ;; some comment
  ...)
```

How can I modify er/expand-region (or another function) so that after expanding to the full function it expands the comments right above the function before expanding to the whole buffer?

Answer (score 3):

From Magnar Sveen, the creator of the package expand-region, taken from his [github](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el):

> Example:
>
> Let's say you want expand-region to also mark paragraphs and pages in
>   text-mode. Incidentally Emacs already comes with mark-paragraph and
>   mark-page. To add it to the try-list, do this:

```
 (defun er/add-text-mode-expansions ()   (make-variable-buffer-local
 'er/try-expand-list)   (setq er/try-expand-list (append
                             er/try-expand-list
                             '(mark-paragraph
                               mark-page))))
```

> (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'er/add-text-mode-expansions)
>
> Add that to
>   its own file, and add it to the expand-region.el-file, where it says
>      "Mode-specific expansions"
>
> Warning: Badly written expansions might slow down expand-region
>   dramatically. Remember to exit quickly before you start traversing the
>   entire document looking for constructs to mark.

I would say you could add "er/mark-paragraph" to the expand-region list, that should do it.

Comment: looks good, thanks a lot: it probably could get me started but... I'm really not very good at elisp yet.  How can I find the expand-region list and try to add er/mark-paragraph to it?

Comment: Take a look at `expand-region.el`. I believe it is a really nice to learn some elisp. Magnar posted a lot of comments at it, if you have questions feel free to ask here!

Comment: it's working now, thanks a lot, +1... I'm answering my own question too with the detailed steps in case anyone wants to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Following user *Dualinity's* advice, I added the following to *clojure-mode-expansions.el* (can be done for other modes than Clojure of course) :

```
;; added this line at the beginning of the file
(require 'org-mode-expansions)
```

Then I added the line er/mark-paragraph to the expand list inside the `er/add-clojure-mode-expansions` method:

```
(defun er/add-clojure-mode-expansions ()
  "Adds clojure-specific expansions for buffers in clojure-mode"
  (set (make-local-variable 'er/try-expand-list) (append
                                                  er/try-expand-list
                                                  '(er/mark-clj-word
                                                    er/mark-clj-regexp-literal
                                                    er/mark-paragraph ; added this line
                                                    er/mark-clj-function-literal))))
```

I restarted Emacs (not too sure as to what was needed to be sure it was taken into account so I restarted the whole thing).

And that's it: now expanding selects "outer" function comments too.

Comment: Well done! Did you need it for the Clojure mode? I guess it couldn't have been more learnful for both of us :)

Comment: @Dualinity: Ideally I'd need it for all the modes where I use this kind of comments but as of now that would mainly be Clojure and some elisp (and maybe for // comments in Java too).  But this gets me started as I'm mostly doing Clojure at the moment : )